# PreferenceScreen class not found

Tags: java, android, xml, sharedpreferences

I have this in preferences.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="displayNotification"
        android:title="Display notification"
        />

    <ListPreference
        android:entries="@array/languages"
        android:key="language"
        />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

PreferencesActivity.java, the class that uses this xml

```
public class PreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

And I have it declared in the manifest like this

```
<activity android:name="com.tellthetime.PreferencesActivity" />
```

When I start the activity I get a class not found exception, which I don't understand.

```
05-17 00:35:13.633: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tellthetime/com.tellthetime.PreferencesActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class PreferenceScreen
05-17 00:35:13.633: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
05-17 00:35:13.633: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
05-17 00:35:13.633: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
05-17 00:35:13.633: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
05-17 00:35:13.633: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-17 00:35:13.633: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-17 00:35:13.633: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
05-17 00:35:13.633: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-17 00:35:13.633: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-17 00:35:13.633: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
05-17 00:35:13.633: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
05-17 00:35:13.633: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-17 00:35:13.633: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class PreferenceScreen
05-17 00:35:13.633: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
05-17 00:35:13.633: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
05-17 00:35:13.633: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
05-17 00:35:13.633: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
05-17 00:35:13.633: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
05-17 00:35:13.633: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1622)
05-17 00:35:13.633: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at com.tellthetime.PreferencesActivity.onCreate(PreferencesActivity.java:13)
05-17 00:35:13.633: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-17 00:35:13.633: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
05-17 00:35:13.633: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     ... 11 more
05-17 00:35:13.633: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.PreferenceScreen in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@44c067e8
05-17 00:35:13.633: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
05-17 00:35:13.633: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
05-17 00:35:13.633: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
05-17 00:35:13.633: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:466)
05-17 00:35:13.633: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:544)
05-17 00:35:13.633: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
05-17 00:35:13.633: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
05-17 00:35:13.633: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212):     ... 19 more
```

This was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765412/android-app-crashes-immediately-when-preferences-screen-is-started) but no one answered. As pointed out in that thread by Heiko Rupp, android is looking for the class in the package `android.view`, but the class is in `android.preferences`, this really lost me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're getting confused, you're trying to set the *preference* definition as the *layout* definition. First set a layout for the Activity, then bind your preferences XML:

```
  ...
  setContentView(R.layout.layout);
  addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
  ...
```

Comment: Yeah, I believed so, but I thought I should add it so the distinction was clear.

Comment: july 2011: `addPreferencesFromResource` is marked deprecated. Use `PreferenceFragment` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The setContentView is not for PreferenceScreen, just "addPrerencesFromResource(R.**.yourPreference);" well.
And your activity for the yourPreference view should inherits PreferenceActivity but not Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `setContentView()` method in `PreferenceActivity`.

```
public class PreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
   }
}
```

Although it's Deprecated. use [Preference Fragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html) instead.