# PreferenceScreen class not found

Tags: java, android

I have a simple preferences.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        <PreferenceCategory
                android:title="First Category">
                <CheckBoxPreference
....
```

My android version is 2.1 (API7) java is 1.6, use eclipse indigo.
In the package explorer there is *android.jar* and after I opened it there is *android.preference* package.

Even so I get the following error:

```
com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
The following classes could not be found:
- PreferenceCategory (Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
- PreferenceScreen (Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
```

What should I do?
Thanx in advance

Comment: which folder inside **res** have you placed your *preferences.xml* file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PreferenceScreen class not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025349/preferencescreen-class-not-found)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If preferences.xml is not in res/xml you should move it there. I am guessing that it could be the source of your problem.

Comment: It was the problem. So I can't view/manage the preferences screen in the graphical editor?

Comment: I don't think so. The tutorials that I have used for my own stuff all assume that you create an activity and load the preferences from a xml file.